# Add site module error

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

I am trying to add an SXA module on a site node. Right-click site node > Scripts > Add site module.
I am getting the below error in SPE logs.

> 19528 00:27:22 INFO  Script item set to
> master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA -
> Scaffolding\Content Editor\Context Menu\Add Site Module in
> ScriptSession
> $scriptSession$|pei2g11lvrnhjedgzo3cee5x|8c329f12-7dfd-4d4e-9846-2220e4aa8130.
>
> ManagedPoolThread #12 00:27:24 ERROR **You cannot call a method on a
> null-valued expression.**

[image]

I tried to debug the script - `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Scaffolding/Content Editor/Context Menu/Add Site Module`
By setting up the required context details as inputs.
Here, `$SiteItem.Modules` is null because of which I suspect the actual error is coming.

**Questions**:

- From where this Modules information is coming or which item I could find this Modules information and why is it null?

Any fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Check in sitecore/system for powershell items, there should be something missing item in inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the base template in the Site Node template was missing the `_Modules template`
`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Scaffolding/_Modules`
So, after adding this, the script error has been resolved.

[image]